# Is it possible for logger.debug to produce error if logging level is info

Tags: java, logging

I'm new to loggers and I just wanted to ask if i will get an error if my log level is info, then i have something like:

```
logger.debug("hello " + object.getMethod());
```

And it is not inside an if block like below:

```
if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled){...}
```

Also, will it have an impact on the time that an application may respond. If its not inside the if block statement?

Comment: How do i know if the framework allows lazily built messages. Does java 6 support it?

Comment: Thaks soo much for the answersss, now it makes sense to me. Thanks for your help as well

Answer (score 0):

All the log methods check for the level internally too. The reason we have `isXYZEnabled` methods if for performance.

Consider the following call:

```java
logger.debug("Value of myObject is: " + hugeObject.toString());
```

and assume that `hugeObject` is, as its name suggests, huge. Constructing a string representation of it might be both time and memory consuming, and ultimately pointless, since after you created the string, nothing will be logged if the level isn't set to debug. Instead, you could explicitly check the level before performing this converstion, and save the time it could have taken:

```java
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Value of myObject is: " + hugeObject.toString());
}
```

Comment: Though most modern logging frameworks provide overloads for lazily-built messages. For instance, something like: `logger.debug("Value of myObject is: {}", myObject)`.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense, additional question tho lets say my method object.getMethod() returns a string value, will that have such a huge impact on performance?

Comment: @VincentGregory depends on how costly it is to create this string (which is tightly correlated to its size)

Comment: Ok thank you so much. You absolutely answered my question. Thank for your helppppp